# Unable to get value of input form via ref in React

Tags: javascript, meteor, reactjs

I'm relatively new to react, and despite seeing this example working on a tutorial video I can't get it to work:

```
import React from 'react';
import Form from 'muicss/lib/react/form';
import Input from 'muicss/lib/react/input';
import Textarea from 'muicss/lib/react/textarea';
import Button from 'muicss/lib/react/button';

export default class blogCreate extends React.Component {
addBlog(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
        var blogTitle = this.refs.title.value;
        var blogContent = this.refs.content.value;
        var user = Meteor.userId();
        console.log(blogTitle, blogContent, user);
        Meteor.call('blogAdd', blogTitle, blogContent, user);
}
render() {
    return(
        <Form onSubmit={this.addBlog.bind(this)}>
            <legend>Add a blog post</legend>
            <Input name='title' label="Title" ref="title" />
            <Textarea name='text' label="Text" ref="content" />
            <Button variant="raised" type="submit">Submit</Button>
        </Form>

    )
  }
}
```

When I output the console.log(blogTitle, blogContent, user) the user Id appears correctly but blogTitle and blogContent are undefined. If I console.log(this.ref.title) and look at the object, there is no value property on that object, despite the content of the Title  being populated.

I'm using react 15.3.0.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you're supposed to be using ref's?  Where is this component initialized?  Typically data is passed down to the component using props.

https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/more-about-refs.html#the-ref-returned-from-reactdom.render

Answer (score 0):

The ref="title" and ref="content" were being associated with the  and  components instead of the  divs they were creating, so that is why my ref values were empty. When I replaced those components with actual 's, it worked as expected.

Answer (score 0):

`refs` return a different value depending whether you're using them on DOM components or composite components.

In your case it looks although `<Input />` and `<Textarea />` are composite components so `this.refs.title` and `this.refs.content` will reference the backing instances, not the DOM nodes.

You can get the DOM node from the instance by using [`ReactDOM.findDOMNode`](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/top-level-api.html#reactdom.finddomnode), e.g. `ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.refs.title).value` (assuming the `<Input />` component returns the `<input />` node as the root element, otherwise you may need to query for the input, e.g. `ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.refs.title).getElementByTagName('input').value`)